# Name or service not known when Java Application call an external hostname define in openshift

Tags: openshift

My Java application needs to call another application with specific URL construct with specific format (ex : aaa.bbb.my-other-application.com).

On OpenShift where my java application is deployed and OK, I created :

An endpoint to declare this specific URL :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-application
  namespace: exe-aa01
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 12.13.14.15 
    ports:
      - port: 6789
        name: external-application
        protocol: TCP
```

An external service

```
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata:
    name: "external-application"
  spec:
    type: ExternalName
    externalName: aaa.bbb.my-other-application.com
  selector: {}
```

But when my Java application calls the URL, the message "Name or service not known" is return

This is OpenShift declaration :

```
oc get endpoints
NAME                              ENDPOINTS           AGE
aaa.bbb.my-other-application.com  12.13.14.15:6789    67m

oc get svc
NAME                              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP               
                 PORT(S)                         AGE       
external-application              ExternalName   <none>           aaa.bbb.my-other-application.com      <none>                          75m
```

Comment: if "aaa.bbb.my-other-application.com" is defined in your DNS, you do not need any of those manifests, right? why do you need a service and an endpoint to reach such an url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to tell you that in our environnement, url is not in the DNS (but in production yes). So we have add the url in the container host file with  hostAliases only for our environnement with patchesStrategicMerge and it's ok